# Ajax post to C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

**EDIT**

So after lookng around I found "right way" I guess. it using a combination of JSON.stringify and creating a model as stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013024/ajax-post-data-null-in-mvc3-controller-method). I still don't understand why the original way did not work, because it is exactly like the first option mention in the post. Oh well thanks guys.

So I have a very simple function in my controller which is a part of my MVC project in C#

```
public string myMethod(String something){
 return "This String"
}
```

And this is my ajax post call in javascript

```
.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "myController/myMethod",
 data: data,
 dataType: text,
 success: function(results){
  console.log(results),
 }
});
```

When I do the ajax call it does return me "This String", but when I have it return something like this

```
 public string myMethod(String something){
  string ret = "This String = " + something 
 return ret
}
```

it gives me "This String =", but the param something is not being added . Am I passing the data wrong?  Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think you copy-pased something wrong. Both C# methods return the same string.

Comment: are you telling that in c# code you are getting `something` variable null?

Comment: What does your `data` object in the ajax request look like?

Comment: @MuctadirDinar I think it is null, because when I print it out in the console in the success comeback it is undefined.

Comment: @AndreiV {"firstData": aData, "SecondData": data2} where aData, and data2 are varaibles

Comment: Your method expects one parameter with the name `something` and you are calling it with two parameter out of whom none are named `something`. Change the `data` object to `{something: aData}`, and check again.

Comment: @AndreiV it did not work

Answer (score 3):

The C# method is a `GET` one, so everything's mixed up.

You should either make the C# method respond to `POST` method

```
[HttpPost]
public string myMethod(String something){
    return "This String"
}
```

or ajax a `GET` request (you'll have to change the way you call it, though):

```
.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: string.Format("myController/myMethod?something={0}", data),
 dataType: text,
 success: function(results){
  console.log(results),
 }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding the httPost and making sure that both the param in the data I am sending and the one that the method is expecting are the same still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to return JSON result:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult returnthis(string text)
{
   return Json(new { Success = text},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` for a `POST`